# Google maps Zoom and Pan buttons not showing! And it is not a css issue for sure

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have a google map on my site and the map zoom and pan buttons are not displaying. I added css

Here are my Map options:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center : new google.maps.LatLng(22.491629,83.901082),
    zoom : 6,
    minZoom : 6,
    panControl:true,
    zoomControl:true,
    mapTypeControl:true,
    scaleControl:true,
    streetViewControl:true,
    overviewMapControl:true,
    rotateControl:true,
    zoomControlOptions : {
      position : google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    },
    panControlOptions : {
      position : google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP,
    },
    mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    // styles : mapStyle,
  }

var mapElement = document.getElementById('map'); 
map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
```

And here is the CSS i have seen on other stackexchange answers, but not working for me

```
<style>
  #mapholder img {
    max-width: none !important;
  }
  #map img { max-width: none !important; }
  /* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
  .ie6 img {
      width:100%;
  }
  .gm-style img { max-width: none !important; }
  .gm-style label { width: auto !important; display: inline; }
</style>
```

And the HTML for the map

```
<div id="mapholder">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/q2Lwd/

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be because you have not initialised the map to run, so it will not display.

You can do this by adding this line of code to your javascript:

`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

and putting your map options in an `initialise` function.

**Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAeLq**

**EDIT: I have also noticed that you have missed this link :**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, I have initialized the map, otherwise I would not be able to see it right? Since it is working on codepen, does it make sense that some other dependency in my code is preventing the zoom buttons from showing?

Comment: it will probably be a silly mistake like the initialise function that you have called has been mispelt - also, what browser do you use?

Comment: As I pointed out you have missed out the link to the API - that is why your map isn't showing

Comment: thanks. i was a silly mistake. I just deleted everything and rewrote the code. it worked. thanks.

Comment: no problem - I thought it might be something like that, it always happens to me!